# QTableWidget Expand Columns to Fill With Last Column Fixed Width

Tags: python, qtablewidget, pyside2

I'm attempting something that I thought would be simple, but just cannot find a way to do this.
The supplied image demonstrates what I'm after. It's essentially just a QTableWidget with the following behaviour:

- Fill the available space.
- A *fixed width* column on the right.
- The rest of the columns I'd like to be able to resize manually (so they'd have to stretch proportionally so that all space is filled).

Things I have tried:

- Setting setStretchLastSection(True). This fills up the space, but you have no control over its width if this is set.
- Overriding the resizeEvent and calculating and setting everything manually. This seems like a very messy way of doing things, which usually means there's a simpler way.

Is there a simple way of achieving this?

[image: QtableWidget Desired Columns]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get something that works

```py
self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Interactive)
self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
self.myTable.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Fixed)
```

The general rule is to set all of the headers to `Interactive`, the penultimate to `Stretch`, and final to `Fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always `ResizeToContents` all columns with `self.my_table.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)` and then apply your fixed width to the last one

Comment: As you can see from the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtWidgets/QHeaderView.html#PySide2.QtWidgets.PySide2.QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeMode) setting `QHeaderView.ResizeToContents` means that "The size cannot be changed by the user or programmatically."